# Facebook login with Parse in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm trying to create a Facebook log in with Parse. Please check out my app delegate's code:

```
    import UIKit

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool  {
    //  verride point for customiztion after application launch.
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
    Parse.setApplicationId("REMOVED", clientKey:"REMOVED")

    return true
}
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication,
            withSession:PFFacebookUtils.session())
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

 }
```

Here's my bridging header (which I think is all ok):

```
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>
    #import "BMParseManager.h"
    #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

    #import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

I am now at the stage of coding my view controller.

I found this example online in Objective-C, so I'm guessing if I can convert this into swift it will work correctly? (Login section of [this page](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios).)

I am getting a error with `PFFacebookUtils`: "Expected declaration". This is in my view controller:

```
    import UIKit

    class FBLoginViewController: UIViewController {    

PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
(user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if user == nil {
NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
} else if user.isNew {
NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
} else {
NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")
}
})
```

Is the import in the bridging header not enough? How can I get the view controller to recognize I imported it into the bridging header - or should I be doing something elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to define your permissions first.

```
var permissions = ["public_profile"]


   PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
```

If you imported your headers correctly it should show no errors in Xcode when you call parse/facebook functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the compiler expects a declaration, that is a variable declaration or method declaration.

It looks like you have the PFFacebookUtils.loginWithPermission(...) code directly inside the class. You need to put it inside a method. For example:

```
import UIKit

class FBLoginViewController: UIViewController {

    func login() {
        //
        PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
            //
        }
    }
})
```